# Accessing Parent controller variables in child controllers Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have an issue, i would like to take your suggestion on this.
I have used child controller inside parent controller div . e,g,

```
<div ng-controler="parent">
    <div ng-controler="child"></div>
</div>
```

And in the js file , 
I have used `module.controller("Parent")` syntax for defining controller. 
I am not using $scope in controler for storing variables but i am using `var self = this;` and have all the variables on self object. Now i want to use parent variables inside child controller. as i am not using scope so i am unable to use this syntax `$scope.parent`. variables in child controllers.

Can you please advise on this that how to use parent controller variable in child controller. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Answered brilliantly at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the question. In the parent controller, add the following line:

```
$scope.parent = self;
```

Now in the child controller, since its scope inherits from the parent scope, you can use

```
$scope.parent.foo
```

to access the foo attribute of the parent controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i am not using $scope to store variables for the dom elements. i am storing it in a self variable using var self= this; so i cant use parent scope variable in child as i have not kept variable on scope.

Comment: I understand what you did. You initialized a local variable named `self` to `this` in the parent controller. What makes you think that will help you access the parent controller from the child? It won't.

Comment: It can be done but by below mentioned way.HTML

<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl as pc">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as cc">
        <pre>{{cc.parentCities | json}}</pre>
        <pre>{{pc.cities | json}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
JS

function ParentCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.cities = ["NY", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona"];
}

function ChildCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    ParentCtrl.apply(vm, arguments); // Inherit parent control

    vm.parentCities = vm.cities;
}. but i using different syntax for defining controller i.e. var a =module;  module.controller('controller name').