# Find parent scope property in Controllers just like in Templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there an easy way to read a property defined in one of the parents scopes from a controller? Just like Angular does in templates, as the docs explains:

> When Angular evaluates {{name}}, it first looks at the scope associated with the given element for the name property. If no such property is found, it searches the parent scope and so on until the root scope is reached. In JavaScript this behavior is known as prototypical inheritance, and child scopes prototypically inherit from their parents.

But this behaviour is not applied inside controllers, if you write `$scope.name` it just looks in the current scope.

Comment: Can you show code example, because child scope always can get props from parent scope in simple way $scope.someParentProp or {{someParentProp}}, or maybe you have isolated scope.

Comment: It's exactly the same with controllers.

Comment: It's the same for methods but not for properties

Comment: 1- Add `window.scope = $scope` to your controller.
2-

Answer (score 0):

Very easily done: `$scope.$parent.name`

See [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) at the bottom for reference.

### Edit

Scope properties from any parent in the hierachical tree can be retrieved by naming the controllers as posted in this SO answer: [angularjs Access parent scope from child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller) and accessing them by the named parent.

Comment: I know that workaround, but it doesn't work if the property is in an upper level, I would have to iterate over '$parent' property until find it. That's why I'm asking for a easier way.

Comment: I think that naming controllers is an ugly solution, in OO programming you don't need to indicate the parent class name in order to access it inherited properties

Comment: JavaScript isn't exactly an OO programming language, nor is Angular.

Comment: That's true, but it's confusing to have a different behaviour between templates and controllers in this subject

Comment: I can certainly relate to that!