# Parent id of scope Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access or manipulate a scope's parent's parent without getting too too complicated. The controller as fashion allows for naming the parent controller as such: `this.applicationCtrl.something` given applicationCtrl > parent1Ctrl > child1Ctrl - siblingOfChild1Ctrl

To give you a better example, I have an applicationCtrl on the `<body>` tag, I have a side panel with `sidePanelCtrl` and the content with `contentCtrl` with a nested `contentChildCtrl`

With the controller as model, I can call or change things on the `sidePanelCtrl` by calling `this.sidePanelCtrl`, can I do the same if I just want to use `$scope` method?

This is specifically for the `contentChildCtrl` where I do not want to write `$scope.$parent.$parent` which still will only get me to the `applicationCtrl` and not the `sidePanelCtrl`

Comment: Can you try with $scope.$parent ?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller). I hope it will give you some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the nesting level of the parent scope, or don't want to type `$scope.$parent.$parent` etc you can attach something like this to a service:

```
angular.module('app').service('inherit', function () {
  var inherit = function(scope, item) 
    if (!scope) return;
    if (scope[item]) return scope[item];
    return inherit(scope.$parent, item);
  }
  return inherit;
}
```

If your namespacing isn't great then it might not help much, but if you're looking to modify, say, the sidebar contents from a grandchild scope, you could call `var sidebarNav = inherit($scope, 'sidebarNav');` in the grandchild controller.

Edit - Better to put this in a service than on `$rootScope` as the comment below has mentioned

Edit: updated to use service

Comment: far better to recommend a service than even thinking about `$rootScope`.

Comment: Updated to show it as a service. Thanks charlieftl for the suggestion

Comment: This is PERFECT! Except one last thing :) It doesnt solve the parent parent then sibling of that's scope.

Comment: sibling scopes won't be inherited in the traditional way. i would recommend moving anything that must be shared into the parent controller. there are other ways to get things like events (`$broadcast`) but sibling scopes sharing data is usually a sign that the parent scope should instantiate the data instead