# Can we use more than one controller in same div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I use two different controllers in the same `div` element?

How does one access the parent controller model data from inside a child controller?

e.g

```
<div ng-controller="abc">
    <div ng-controller="def"><span>{{name}}</span></div>
</div>
```

Suppose the model `name` is in controller `abc` then how does one access its value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs Access parent scope from child controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS automatically look up from the first `$scope` to the parent till the `$rootScope` to find the property matching `name`.
Thus to answer your question, if the controller `def` doesn't have a property named `name`, it is already visible. Otherwise, you should use:

```
{{$parent.name}}
```

In your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is by having an alias. See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/doBKjHRmh35kU2zJxYsG?p=preview)

In your html it would look like

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as Alias">
    {{Alias.foo}}
```

In your javascript it would look like

```
function Ctrl(){
    this.foo = "bar"
}
```