# How to access parent controller data inside child controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can we access model data of parent controller inside child controller

```
<div ng-controller="abc">
    <div ng-controller="def">
        <span> {{name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

can we access "model" value is it belongs in "abc" controller?

Comment: Just access it like `{{model}}` it will be available in child scope.

Comment: It definitely takes {{name}} from the parent controller if there is no such in child controller....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will help you. you can be able to access parent controller using $parent.

```
<script>
    function abc($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Pragnesh"
    }
    function def($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Test"
    }
</script>
<html ng-app="">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="abc">
       <div ng-controller="def">
          <span> {{name}}</span>
          <span> {{$parent.name}}</span>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Sushil Kumar if you satisfied with answer so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $parent (i.e. $scope.$parent), this will refer to the parent scope of a controller.

It is also explained here: [AngularJS access parent scope from child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)