# Angular, Why does the child controller have same scope as parent?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a test located on plunker at this address: [Full example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6plhAhKumZTJMAg6hPQ?p=preview)

Here is the child controller which works:

```
  child.directive('child', function(){
    return{
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl: 'child.html',
      link: function(){},
      controller:['$scope', function($scope){
        this.inherited = $scope.test;
        this.local = "child";
      }],
      controllerAs:'child'
    };
  });
```

I am expecting the controller located in child.js to be a child controller of the controller in script.js. This would mean that if I want to access a variable added to the scope of parent controller from the child controller, I would need to access it using $scope.$parent. Can someone explain why these are the same scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, directives do not create a new scope.  So in your example $scope in the directive will be the same value as the scope that the controller is contained in.  The scope is not inherited - they are the same scope.

So for this markup:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
    <child></child>
</div>
```

scope in SomeController will be the exact same object as scope in your directive.  If you did $scope.$parent in the directive, you would actually be accessing the parent scope of SomeController.  This is equivalent to

```
scope: false //default for directives
```

If you add:

```
scope: true
```

to your directive definition, then the directive will create a new scope that prototypically inherits from the parent scope.  In this situation,

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
    <child></child>
</div>
```

Now $scope.$parent in the directive will be the $scope of SomeController.  Also, since it prototypically inherits, the directive will have access to methods and properties defined on $scope.$parent, with the caveats and complications that come with prototypically inheritance in javascript.

If you use:

```
scope: {}
```

Now $scope.$parent in the directive will still be the $scope of SomeController, but the new scope will not prototypically inherit from the parent, so you will not have access to methods and properties defined on $scope.$parent.

Answer (score 0):

The child scope inherits from the parent scope, so anything you define in the parent will appear in the child scope. Keep in mind that this is a new scope, so modifications won't affect the parent directly without using the `$scope.$parent` scope. Take a look at this question and the accepted answer: [AngularJS access parent scope from child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Comment: Except that in directives the parent scope is inherited by default, so you don't have to use $parent to access these values.

Answer (score 0):

In directives the parent scope is inherited by default:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes