# How to hide show in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am beginner in angular js

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="maincontrol">
        <div ng-show="!vis"><a href="#/">show</a></div>
        <div ng-show="vis"><a href="#/contact">hide</a></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])
app.controller('maincontrol', function ($scope) {
    $scope.vis = true;
     $scope.fun = function () {

        if ($scope.user == "home" && $scope.pass == "home") {
            console.log($scope.user, $scope.pass);
            $scope.vis = false;
        }
    }
})


app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'contact.html'
        })
});
```

and also i have two html pages like

home.html

```
<div ng-controller="maincontrol">
    <input ng-model="user"/>
    <input ng-model="pass"/>

    <div ng-click="fun()">
        click
    </div>
</div>
```

contact.html

```
<div>
    contact
</div>
```

my expectation is after entering home into user and pass. if i click 'click' i need to show 'show' label instead of 'hide'. pls help me.

Comment: each controller has its own scope, when you wrote $scope.vis=false on fun(), you actually created a new variable on maincontroler1 scope. If you expected this variable to affect the view which is binded to maincontroler scope, it won't happen.

Comment: @ Or Guz. understand. without this how can i do that? pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each controller has its own scope, when you wrote $scope.vis=false on fun(), you actually created a new variable on maincontroler1 scope. If you expected this variable to affect the view which is binded to maincontroler scope, it won't happen.

I suggest 2 options:

1. You can use one controller for entire app **(If you use same controller in two tags it will still create a new scope although it is the same controller)**, this way the fun() method that was called from the first view will change the boolean in the single controller and will affect the second view. **Please note when you use ng-view you will have to get the variable from the parent**.

So I used this code:

```
$parent.user 
$parent.pass
```

Create this [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9vBVWgE4rcRuSNaySbuh?p=preview) for you.

2. Share the vis boolean between 2 controllers using a service. You can
   use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers) for this option.
3. You can also use reach parent controller scope from child controller, that can be done if ng-view will be nested in the outer controller. You can use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller) for option 3.

Comment: See my last edit, just before you posted that it is not working.  When you use <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="maincontrol"> and remove other ng-controller tags?

Comment: @Neophyte, I created a working plunker for you. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort dear.