# parent scope not getting updated in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am having two controllers -

**Parent Controller**

```
dashboardApp.controller("parentController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.rootRules = {blackRule: "", blueRule: "", greenRule: "", yellowRule: "", orangeRule: "", redRule: ""};
```

So as you can see it has a variable called rootRules which I am updating in the child controller as -

**Child Controller**

```
            var color = $scope.color + "Rule";
            $scope.rootRules[color] = ruleString;
            console.log($scope.rootRules);
```

So it works when `rootRules` is having `""` for that color however when the `rootRules` have some string stored in it for that color then I am unable to see the updates on screen for this code. Please let me know if full code required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access and modify the parent scope like this:

```
$scope.$parent.rootRules[color] = ruleString;
```

More in depth answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21454647/3858736

Comment: Hey Matt, its still not updating

Comment: Ok its updated things in the variable but its not changing the look and feel of code.

Comment: update was done http://screencloud.net/v/odBG however no update on screen actually

Comment: I put together an example to attempt to match the basics of your problem, see http://jsfiddle.net/2r728/504/

Comment: You do not need to include the `$scope` in your HTML.  See updated http://jsfiddle.net/2r728/506/

Comment: ok its working, I am not sure why its not working in my case, would u like to see whole code?