# AngularJS directive in directive is not setting up scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a controller, with `$scope.colorHex` value

For example I have the directive `colorpickerTooltip` and in the template I call another directive: `<colorpicker ng-model="colorHex"></colorpicker>`

then in the second directive (`colorpicker`) I set up controller's value:

`scope.colorHex = '#cecece';`

and then in the second directive I call method `scope.doIt()`, but something is going wrong:

my `$scope` value is not updated! But why, maybe because of my 2-level directive?

How to set up the controller variable value?

Comment: Could you put your code in plunker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs Access parent scope from child controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the problem of two level directive scope. Please read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Define the `colorHex` in your controller as an object like:

```
$scope.dataStore = {};
$scope.dataStore.colorHex = '#cecece';
```

Then modify at first directive as:

```
<colorpicker ng-model="dataStore.colorHex"></colorpicker>
```

And then later use it in your second directive to update in `doIt` method:

```
$scope.doIt = function() {
    $scope.dataStore.colorHex = '#fff';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second directive copies the value from the first one and creates a new object in the second scope. 
You can prevent it via using a objective structure such as

```
$scope.color= {hex=undefined};
```

and change it in the inside scope

```
$scopescope.color.hex = '#cecece';
```

it will prevent this stuation