# AngularJS: Validating dependent fields

Tags: angularjs, validation, directive

I have created an angular directive to validate a list of percentages that must sum up to 100%. The problem is that the validity of one field depends on the validity of another. The first thing I do in my directive is to try and set the form validity to valid to alleviate this - but this requires access to the form INgFormController and I only have direct access to the current form input field

```
link: function ($scope: angular.IScope, element: JQuery, attributes: ITimePercentageAttributes, ctrl: angular.INgModelController /*: IArticleRegistrationsController*/) {
    if (!ctrl) return;

    ctrl.$validators["percentage"] = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
        (<IArticleRegistrationsScope>$scope.$parent.$parent).timeRegistrationForm.$setValidity("percentage", true, ????????)

    //...calculate sum and return true/false...
```

The $setValidity method is missing the third argument here.

The relevant HTML template code is below:

```
<form name="timeRegistrationForm">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        ...
        <table class="table panel-body">
            <thead>
                ...
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="timeAllocation in requisition.TimeAllocations">
                    <td class="adjust-padding-when-xs">
                        <input ng-model="timeAllocation.Percentage"
                                ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                                name="percentage{{$index}}"
                                ng-change="vm.percentageUsedChange(requisition)"
                                min="0"
                                max="100"
                                time-percentage />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ...
            </tbody>
        </table>
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please post the full code or link to plnkr please.

Comment: The ctrl parameter in the code snippet is a INgModelController for the HTML input field for a single percentage. I want to get access to the INgModelController for the parent form. How do you do that?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller

Comment: @jodevan Doesn't look like it -- that's about getting the parent scope as far as I can see. What I need is the INgModelController for a parent element. I only have the INgModelController for the input element that the directive is attached to.