# How to share a variable between multiple modules in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm new to AngularJS and understand the basic principles. However, I'm having a case now where I don't yet know how to get to the solution.

Let me briefly explain you the case. Let's say you have a supermarket webshop where there is an input box where you can type to search for your food. Next to the input box, there is an icon that displays a modal on click with all the most ordered foods.

This modal has it's own controller and the searchpanel in which the inputbox is has it's own controller.

Now when a food is sold out this gets striked through in the modal. But when every popular food is sold out I want the modal not to show on click.

I thought I could assign a variable to the scope of the modal but then I couldn't access it in the scope of the searchbar. I could work with rootScope I think, but I would really like to know if there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance and if you need more info, please let me know.

adev

Comment: You can create a [custom service](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/) and share the data between the controllers

Comment: I completely fail to understand why you would need a shared variable between two unrelated controllers in order to prevent a modal to appear when a link is clicked. Those seem two completely orthogonal problems to me.

Comment: If you have a parent/child controller relationship then the child can access the parent's scope via $scope.$parent.xyz. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can use $watch on your food object/var if any changes happen $broadcast it your change to all and then in your child/modal control catch it with $on.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Angular Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

**Also:**

[passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

[how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers#answer-12009408)