# AngularJS: Call JSON array value in nested Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How to call Json array value in other controller. Basically i work with nested controller. Nested controller will return first character of firstname and lastname.

For example if my first name is Anand Jee then It will return AJ, Rohan Kumar then it will return RK.

My AngularJS code.

```
//create module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

//create controller

myApp.controller("empCtrl", function ($scope) {
    var Employees = [
        { FirstName: "Anand", LastName: "Jee", Roles: "Web Developer", Technology: ".NET" },
        { FirstName: "Pritus", LastName: "Dubey", Roles: "Window App Developer", Technology: "XAMARIN" },
        { FirstName: "Vineet", LastName: "Rai", Roles: "Web Developer", Technology: ".NET" },
        { FirstName: "Nilesh", LastName: "Pathak", Roles: "UI/UX Developer", Technology: "Photoshop" },
        { FirstName: "Vikesh", LastName: "Juyal", Roles: "Web Developer", Technology: "PHP" }
    ];
    $scope.Employees = Employees;
});

myApp.controller("EmpShortName", function ($scope) {
    $scope.getEmpShortName = function () {

        //$scope.empShortName  = $scope.Employees.FirstName + " " + $scope.Employees.LastName;//here is problem
        $scope.empShortName = "NP";//For temp declaration
        return $scope.empShortName;
    };
});
```

[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/8cw9anm9dEbAvtYltpfF?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs Access parent scope from child controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `Employee` object into the `getEmpShortName` function. Then just return the parsed value. Also, no need for the `EmpShortName` controller, just put the scope function in your `empCtrl` controller:

HTML:

```
<div class="empTextImage">{{getEmpShortName(emp)}}</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getEmpShortName = function (emp) {
    return emp.FirstName.substr(0,1) + emp.LastName.substr(0,1);
};
```

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kIqdflFz38yJ40rEECsO?p=preview)