# what does $parent mean in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am completely new to AngularJS. In the code I am supposed to add a feature to I can see $scope.$parent I know about $scope. I also know that when I see a $ it means it is  built-in angular. So I searched for it in [Angular web site](https://angularjs.org) but 
I did not have any luck finding anything about $Parent as a built-in service or factory or directive, etc...
Can anybody help me understand what it means. Also how I can get to an answer in their documentation when I run into something new?

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller

Comment: most of the time you see $parent .. it's from poor practices. It has been abused a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation for $parent is sparse, but you can find it referenced [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) at the very bottom of the page.

$scope.$parent refers to the $scope of the parent element. E.g. if you have an element with a controller nested within another element with it's own controller:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
  ... something in the parent element
  <div ng-controller="childController">
     ... something in the child element
  </div>
</div>
```

You can access variables attached to the parentController from the childController using $scope.$parent. and use them in the child element.

Comment: +adding minor detail:
All the parent properties will be accessible in child controller by default with exception of isolated scope.
We can make use of $parent where we have a property with same name in both child and parent controller. In this case child property shadows parent controller property.

Answer (score 7):

In angular, your scopes are all chained together.  So, you can reference the scope "above" your immediate scope with $parent.

It's useful, for example, if you are working with a directive (or if you have a controller inside of another).