# parent controller Json value is not changed from child controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For example my parent controller variable name is

```
$scope.studentInfo = {
    studentId: 1,
    name: 'aaaa',
    address: {
        doorno: 153,
        street: 'Gandhi street'
    }
}
```

I am changing the this parent variable through child controller example, changing the variable to some other value

```
$scope.student = angular.copy($scope.studentInfo);
$scope.studnet.address.doorno = 150;
$scope.studentInfo = $scope.student;
```

then if we assigning the value to parent controller, then the value will be changing alone in child controller but not parent controller. If I assign each and every property then the value will reflect in parent json also.

Comment: how do you access the parent $scope from the child $scope?

Comment: First I will assign this parent variable to my child controller variable  For example $scope.userInfo = $scope.studentInfo

Comment: Primitives are passed by value, objects by reference.

Comment: I mean do you use `$scope.$parent` or how do you access it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21454647/2419215

Comment: No you can directly access the variable in child controller

Comment: If we using angular copy to avoid unnecessary changes because of that only we should assign the each and every property manually.

Comment: @ParthipanS You could use a `factory` to capture the changes between controllers.