# Unable to update Child controllers scope valriable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im new to angular js and im not able to figure out how to change the child controller scope variable from parent controller. Here is the code snippet for that:

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

var parentCtrl = function($rootScope, $scope, shareService, $log){ 
    shareService.setDetails($scope.pdetails);
}

var mainCtrl1 = function($rootScope, $scope, shareService, $log){
    $scope.msg = "Controller 1";
    $scope.details = shareService.details;//shareService.details;
}

var mainCtrl2 = function($rootScope, $scope, shareService){
    $scope.msg = "Controller 2";
    $scope.details = shareService.details;//shareService.details;
}

parentCtrl.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$scope", "shareService", "$log"];
mainCtrl1.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$scope", "shareService", "$log"];
mainCtrl2.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$scope", "shareService", "$log"];

 mainApp.controller("parentController", parentCtrl)
        .controller("mainController1", mainCtrl1)
        .controller("mainController2", mainCtrl2)
        .factory("shareService", function(){
            var shareData = {
                details : "sadfgs detaisdfadsfasdf..",
                setDetails: function(value){
                    this.details = value;
                }
            };
            return shareData;
        });
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Views</title>
      <script src='lib/angular.js'></script>
      <script src='js/mainApp.js'></script>
      <script src='js/studentController.js'></script>
   </head>
   
   <body ng-app = 'mainApp' ng-controller='parentController' ng-strict-di>
     <div ng-controller='mainController1'>
       1. Msg : {{msg}}<br/>
          Share Details: {{details}}<br/><br/>
     </div>
     <div ng-controller='mainController2'>
       2. Msg : {{msg}}<br/>
          Share Details: {{details}}<br/><br/>
     </div>
     <input type='text' ng-model='pdetails'/>  
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Plunker link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hJypukqMmdHSEZMVnkDO?p=preview

Comment: maybe you should read this one first : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller

Comment: Thanks @oguzhan00, helpful example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change value of child controller from parent controller you can use $broadcast on $scope.
syntax

```
$scope.$broadcast(event,data);
```

$broadcast is used to trigger an event(with data) to the child scope from current scope.
In child controller use $on to receive the event(with data).

Here id the code snippet:

```
app.controller("parentCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.OnClick=function()
{
  $scope.$broadcast("senddownward",$scope.messege);
}
});
app.controller("childCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.$on("senddownward",function(event,data)
{
  $scope.messege=data;
});
});
```

In this example I am broadcasting the event on ng-click,you can use some other custom event.like $watch on $scope.

See this example
https://plnkr.co/edit/efZ9wYS2pukE0v4JsNCC?p=preview

P.S. you can change the name of event from **senddownward** to whatever you want

Comment: if you find this answer useful you can vote it up :)
REgards

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent's scope properties directly due to the scope inheritance:

```
 <div ng-controller='mainController1'>
      Share Details: {{pdetails}}
 </div>
```

Your example does not work because the controllers get executed only once before the view is rendered, `pdetails` is empty at that moment.

To monitor the changes to `pdetails`, you can use `$watch` in the child controller:

```
$scope.$watch('pdetails', function(newVal) {
  $scope.details = newVal;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alec Kravets, but it will not change respective controllers scope "details" variable.!

Comment: @Shree, you can use `$watch` to monitor the changes to `pdetails`.

Comment: Yes its working with help of "$watch".. I've added $watch to all controllers.

Comment: Check this may be im wrong but its working [link] https://plnkr.co/edit/hJypukqMmdHSEZMVnkDO?p=preview