# How to exchange data between controllers without using a service in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers... `C1` and `C2`, I want to verify a data that I have in `C1` but the verification logic is in `C2`, So how can I pass that data from `C1` to `C2` and get back the result in `C1` ?

I am aware of the services in angular, but for that communication I have to pass all data [Which is too large] from `C1` and `C2` to service which doesn't seem efficient. Any optimized way to do so ?

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: you could use $rootScope, if both controllers falls within one module

Comment: *"doesn't seem efficient"* ... huh? Why not? Why would you try to re-invent the wheel and go against convention?

Comment: @code9215 there is only one rootScope regardless of how many modules get injected into main app module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You have to use a service.

2- If you don't want to then nested controllers inherit scope:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1 as c1">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2 as c2">
      {{c1.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3- Inside controller code you can use the $controller service:

```
.controller('C2', function($scope, $controller) {
    $controller('C1', {$scope: $scope});
});
```

4- Don't use $rootScope to store data.

Comment: I never used "as" feature fro controller names. looks like interesting thing to try. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options if you don't want to use a common service.

1. You can use `$rootScope` to save your shared data.
2. You can get the access to the scope of `C1` from `C2` by selecting an element that comes under `C1`.

Lets say `<div id="myC1Candidate">` is under `C1`. You can do the following to get the scope of `C1` from `C2`

`angular.element(document.getElementById("myC1Candidate")).scope()`

**Note**

*It is wrong to think that using a service is inefficient when you have to share large amount of data. The data is shared by reference when you assign it to a service singleton.*

Answer (score 0):

You can register those C1/C2 controllers in the parent controller and use it as a proxy.

Ref. [AngularJS access parent scope from child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with

Controller 2 (don't forget to inject `$rootScope` as dependency to your controller):

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("notifyC1",{/*mydata*/});
```

Controller 1:

```
$scope.$on("notifyC1",function(evt,data){
  console.log(data)
});
```

but you should really rethink your application design if you have to do that. Store that data and the verification logic in a service and inject it to your controllers.