# What's an elegant way of accessing parent controller's member from child controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using controllerAs syntax in my application, I want to access parent controller's function from child controller, I know this is achievable by injecting $scope, however considering Angular has tried so hard to get rid of the $scope from code, I'd like to know if there is a more elegant way of doing this without injecting $scope?

Here's an example of HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as child">
  </div>
</div>
```

And corresponding controllers:

```
angular.module('test').controller('AppCtrl', function () {
  var vm = this;
  vm.log = function() {
    console.log("Output");
  }
}  

angular.module('test').controller('ChildCtrl', function () {
  var vm = this;
  // Here I want to access parent's log() function
}
```

I know I can inject $scope and then access the log function by `$scope.app.log()`, but is there a bettter way to access log without injecting the `$scope?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs Access parent scope from child controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use Angular 1.5 components ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)).

It would look something like this in child component:

```
.component('childComponent', {
  require: {
    parentCtrl: '^ parentCtrl'
  }
  controller: function() {
    this.parentCtrl.anyMethod(); //here we are accessing parent's controller properties
  }

  ...

});
```

Comment: the plunker link seems broken.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is being posted about 6 months after the question was asked but I think it may be helpful to other visitors to check the solutions I propose below.

Angular controllers have prototypal inheritance, which means the `$scope` object of the parent controller is accessible by the children. If instead of binding your properties and methods to `$scope` you use the `this` keyword and `controller as` syntax, children's `$scope` will not have direct access to the parent's members but you can still access them via `$scope.$parent`.

That said, there are two possible (clean and easy) ways to solve your problem:

1) You can bind properties and methods to the `$scope` object of your parent controller and have direct access to them via `$scope` in any child controller (and you can overwrite properties/methods if you want--like you would on a regular `Class`). 
So if you define

```
$scope.log = function() { console.log("output") }
```

on your parent controller, your child controller has access to it by simply calling `$scope.log()`. [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naxus28/zg0ca7cy/14/).

2) Or, since you are using the `this` keyword and `controller as` syntax to bind the controllers to the views, the child's `$scope` object will not have direct access to the parent's properties and methods because these are not members of the parent's `$scope` but of `this`, the instance of the parent controller itself. In this scenario, you should access the parent via `$scope.$parent`. Among other things, "app" (the alias you created for "AppCtrl", thus the instance of that controller itself) will be a property of `$scope.$parent`. Since you defined the "log" method as a member of the controller itself and not its `$scope` object, "log" is a member of "app" and your child controller can access the parent's "log" method as such: `$scope.$parent.app.log()`. [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naxus28/6xex3wrx/5/)

Here is some further reading on this topic: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes