# AngularJs: Access parent scope and I am getting Scope undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to access a parent scope, but I am getting the error that the scope is undefined.

```
MyApp.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $mdDialog, $window, $location, $mdToast) {

$scope.test = "Test";

}).
controller('ToastCtrl', function($scope, $mdToast, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.openMoreInfo = function(e) {
        if ( isDlgOpen ) return;
        isDlgOpen = true;

        $mdDialog
          .show($mdDialog
            .alert()
            .title($scope.$parent.test)
            .targetEvent(e)
          )
          .then(function() {
              isDlgOpen = false;
          })
    };
});
```

Any suggestion, why I am getting this error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add the html code, where the `ng-controller` is present.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code why you would expect there is a parent scope

Comment: I do not see child-parent relation here, they are siblings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs Access parent scope from child controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are not able to access the value is there is no `parent-child` `relationship` between your `controllers`.

You can access it multiple ways:

1. Either using a `service` to communicate between controllers.
2. Using emit/broadcast to communicate
3. Use `$rootscope`, but its not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted also your view here (at least), but I assume in your html you have something like this

```
<div ng-controller="AdminController">
    <div ng-controller="ToastCtrl">
        <!-- openMoreInfo  called somewhere here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And you what your controller to look for `$scope.test` variable in parent scope. You can just try to use [angularjs scope inheritance](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#scope-inheritance-example) this way

In parent controller change `$scope.test = "Test";` with

```
$scope.Data = {};
$scope.Data.test = "Test";
```

Then in your child controller use `.title($scope.Data.test)`.
The child controller will try to access `$scope.Data` object but it doesn't exist in current scope, so it will try to search for it in `$parent` scope where it can be found.