# scope of controllers angularjs

Tags: angularjs, authentication, scope, controllers

My index.html looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="ExternalCtrl">
  <div ng-include=" 'header.html' "></div>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <div ng-include=" 'footer.html' "></div>
<!-- all scripts, angular modules, directives, services etc.. -->
</body>
```

External controller wrap entire webpage, so I should have access to ExternalCtrl variables wherever in my app for example in headerCtrl which is controller of included header.html file.

I need this because in externalCtrl I get the value from localStorage (which are stored there after success login user) and if its present set a *_authentication.isAuth = true;* so I can develop my page with *ng-if="_authentication.isAuth"* for logged in users and *ng-if="!_authentication.isAuth"* for not logged in.

My externalCtrl code is:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('ExternalCtrl', ['$scope', 'localStorageService',
function($scope, localStorageService) {

    var _authentication = {};

    var _authentication = {
        isAuth: false
    };

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorization');
    if(authData) {

            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            console.log(_authentication.isAuth);

    }

}
]);
```

At this point *console.log* works correctly and log true if it is true or false if its false obviously.

After that I want to check if I have access to that variable in headerCtrl which is controller of included header.html as I mentioned above. So in this controller i add line:

```
console.log(_authentication.isAuth);
```

Which cause following error:

> ReferenceError: _authentication is not defined

1. Why?
2. Is it correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `_authentication` is defined inside the controller. It is not available globally. You can define it on `$scope` or `$rootScope`.

```
 function($scope,$rootScope, localStorageService) {

       $scope._authentication = {};

        $scope._authentication = {
            isAuth: false
        };

        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorization');
        if(authData) {

                $scope._authentication.isAuth = true;
                console.log($scope._authentication.isAuth);

        }

    }
    ]);
```

**For more info**: [AngularJS access parent scope from child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Comment: So in nested controller I dont have access to variables defined in external controller? I thought that i have.

Comment: No, you are just using var inside the parent controller. You have to define the variable on $scope or $rootScope. If you are using $scope, then in child controllers view you have to print {{$parent.val}}