# Call parent method from child app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have checkbox on child app controller, so when user click on it, I need to call some method from parent controller:
Parent app controller:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCntr as parentCntr">
    <child-app></child-app>
</div>
```

Child app:

```
   <div class="child-app" ng-controller="ChildCntr as childCntr">
       <div class="checkbox no-indent">
          <input type="checkbox"
                 name="test"
                 id="test"
                 ng-change="childCntr.DisableText()"
                 ng-model="childCntr.testVar"/>
         <label for="test">Some Text</label>
       </div>
   </div>
```

So, how to do this in easiest way?

Comment: Try `$parent.yourFunction()`

Comment: ng-click="parentCntr.myMethod()" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS access parent scope from child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Comment: For some reason parentCntr.myMethod() doesn't works. Maybe because I am inserting child controller as app?

Comment: That could be the case indeed.

Comment: @Ted So your `child-app` is inside a directive ?

Comment: yes, it is inside

Comment: I must add... The modularity created by Angular, you should really not do this.  You should fire events or pass something up.  Ideally you should be creating self contained components.  Sure, you can do this, but really.... should you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to access to the parent scope you can use $parent like this :

```
<div ng-controller='SecondCtrl' ng-click='$parent.testFunction()'>{{$parent.name}}</div>
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vc9b5wNODwLJnV1WWSjP?p=preview) is a working example.