# How to call function in parent controller from the child controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is my UI Code

```
<div ng-controller="WorkFlowController" ng-init="init()">
  <div ng-controller="templatecontroller">
     <ul class="ng-scope" ng-click="child(1)"></ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is my script in app.js

This is my parent Controller

```
 app.controller("WorkFlowController",  function ($scope) {
  $scope.parentFuntion = function (TaskId) {
   };
 });
```

This is my child Controller

```
 app.controller("templatecontroller",  function ($scope) {
 $scope.child = function (TaskId) {
 parentFuntion(TaskId);
};
  });
```

My issue is that,I got the id in the child controller function but not able to pass to the parent.
Is it possible to pass the id to parent controller function from the child..?
Please help me :) Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller), It contains a lot of great information.

Using `$scope` you can use the `$parent` attribute to access the parent scope as such:

```
$scope.child = function (TaskId) {
    $scope.$parent.parentFuntion(TaskId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**parent Controller**

```
app.controller("WorkFlowController", function ($scope) {
```

$rootScope.parentFuntion = function (TaskId) { }; 
});

**child Controller**

```
app.controller("templatecontroller", function ($scope) { $scope.child = function (TaskId) { $rootScope.parentFuntion(TaskId); }; });
```